# Empty result from sql query in codeigniter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when I execute a sql query in codeigniter using `$this->db->query($sql);` it gave me an empty result. But when I directly execute the same query from mysql it gives me the correct result. If Anyone have faced this problem help me ? 
I have more sql queries in the same project and those are working fine.

query -

```
$sql = 'select r.no from routes r where r.id = 
                    (select rp.route_id from routes_and_places rp where rp.place_id = 
                            (select p.id from places p where p.name = \''.$place.'\'));';
```

When this executes I got exact query by `print_r($sql);` and I executed it directly in mysql and it gave me the expected result.
If anyone know the solution please help

Comment: remove one semi colon `(;)` that you have in your query

Comment: I tried it now. but nothing changed. and first semicolon for query 2nd one for the variable. I think having both semicolons is not an error

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in sql string you passed

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('name',$place);
$sql1 = $this->db->get('places');
$sql1 = $sql1->row();

$this->db->select('route_id');
$this->db->where('place_id',$sql1->id);
$sql2 = $this->db->get('routes_and_places');
$sql2 =  $sql2->row();

$this->db->where('id',$sql2->route_id);
$sql3 = $this->db->get('routes');
$sql3 = $sql3->result();

print_r($sql3);
```

One by one print all result and check that.
Try this !

Comment: can you print query by 
print_r($this->db->last_query());
and check query ?

Comment: yes I did it query is working fine. I think some other thing is wrong

Comment: if this query runs in sql than there shouldn't be any problem in your PHP file just run this query in SQL than if you are using phpmyadmin than you will get an option to generate PHP and just copy they PHP and paste it infront of $sql variable and try it out again.

Comment: @RonakChauhan you have problems in your query as you are passing $sql1= sql2->row it should be $sql1=$sql1-row() and than in send sql command $sql2 in where clause u have place_id , $sql1 it should be $sql1->id

Comment: @imran Yes I made change in it

Comment: this also return empty result - Array()

Comment: @RonakChauhan still you have this problem $sql1 = $sql2->row(); it should be $sql1 = $sql1->row();

Answer (score 0):

Printing directly `print_r($sql);` **won't** give you results. Its just the sql query and now you have to **execute it** and get the **results**. Try this,

```
$sql = "select r.no from routes r where r.id = 
        (select rp.route_id from routes_and_places rp where rp.place_id = 
        (select p.id from places p where p.name = '".$place."'));";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result();

/* print query */
echo $this->db->last_query();

/* print results */
print_r($result);
```

Comment: yes. I mean , I got the exact query with real value for $place variable by calling print_r($sql); and then I copied that query with values for $place and executed that directly in mysql it gave me the expecting result. above code is same to my code. but it gives me empty result.

Comment: Modified your query. Also try debugging your query. Check whether query is generating properly. Check edits.

Comment: I dont understand why this happening when I got query from echo $this->db->last_query(); and copied it and executed it directly in mysql so it gives me the answer but through   $this->db->query($sql); it gives me an empty result

Answer (score 0):

finally I could found the solution. I get values for `$place` variable from google places API. so when I get places although it doesn't visible through `$this->db->last_query();` it contains `CSS` tags for those places. That means google send `CSS` to highlight road names with places. After hours of working on this problem finally I got an error saying incorrect syntax and it showed some `CSS` code in `where clause` that means `$place` contains some `CSS` codes also. So that I remove those `CSS` tags from the String and now it's working fine.

Code to remove `CSS tags/new line characters` and all other things from `Strings` here

```
$text = strip_tags($step->html_instructions,"<style>"); // remove css from text
                    $substring = substr($text,strpos($text,"<style"),strpos($text,"</style>")+2);
                    $text = str_replace($substring,"",$text);
                    $text = str_replace(array("\t","\r","\n"),"",$text);
                    $text = trim($text);
```